# jest mocked axios doesn't return the expected value

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs

I mocked axios during the tests, which is been called in one of my functions, but it's returning undefined instead of what I setted to return.

I already tried several other solutions I found online, but none of them worked.

Function where axios is called:

```
    static getWeather() {
        const apiKey = ""
        const apiRequest = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=" + apiKey
        return axios.get(apiRequest);
    }
}

export default WeatherService
```

`src/__mocks__/axios.js`

```
export default {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
}
```

Test

```
import axios from 'axios';
import WeatherService from '../service/WeatherService';

describe('WeatherService', () => {
    test('Should mock axios', () => {

        const apiKey = ""

        axios.get.mockImplementationOnce( () => {
            Promise.resolve({ data: { response: true } })
        });

        const res = WeatherService.getWeather();
        console.log(res);
        expect(res.data.response).toBe(true);
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=" + apiKey)
    })
})
```

I don't know if it changes anything but I'm using single-spa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing this:

```
axios.get.mockImplementationOnce( () => {
            Promise.resolve({ data: { response: true } })
        });
```

to this:

```
axios.get.mockImplementationOnce( () => Promise.resolve({ data: { response: true } }));
```

?